# Generating a Matrix from a sum of Matrices

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to do MCMC methods on the inverse problem of A(u)x=b, where A is a symmetric positive definite square matrix. I was given that A can be expressed as A = A<sub>0</sub> + Σ<sub>i</sub> u<sub>i</sub> A<sub>i</sub>. I want to check whether the ergodic average converges to the initial u. But I need to create some random matrix A satisfying the conditions to test out my MCMC function.

Is it possible to create such a random matrix A that is of the form of A = A<sub>0</sub> + Σ<sub>i</sub> u<sub>i</sub> A<sub>i</sub> and how can I go about it in python?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to generate SPD (symmetric positive definite) matrices A[0],A[1](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_spd_matrix.html),.. and positive numbers u1,.. and then sum them up

```
B = A[0] + Sum{ i>=1 | u[i]*A[i]}
```

This will be SPD. It would be possible for B to be SPD even though the A[] were not, and the u[] not all positive, but I think that it could be tricky to determine the A[] and the u[] so that B is SPD in that case.

One issue is whether you want B to be strictly positive definite -- ie invertible -- or not. B will be invertible if either A[0] is , or at least one of the A[i], with u[i] > 0, is. Again it B could be invertible even if those conditions were not met, and again it might be tricky to ensure that B was invertible in that case.

There are various ways you could generate a single SPD nxn matrix P:

a/ Generate an upper triangular nxn matrix U and compute

```
P = U'*U
```

P will be SPD, and invertible iff all the diagonal elements of U are non-zero

b/ Generate a mxn matrix M and compute

```
P = M'*M
```

P will be SPD, but not necessarily invertible. It definitely won't be invertible if m<n. To make it invertible, add a positive multiple of the identity matrix.

c/ use sklearn.datasets.make_spd_matrix
eg [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_spd_matrix.html) From the documentation it's not clear to me whether this will be invertible or not, so if you need an invertible one you might be best tp add a multiple of the identity.

Comment: Hi, thank you for helping. I cannot seem to access the link you provided

Comment: Oops, sorry. I hope I've fixed it

Comment: Yep, its working now. Thank you for your help. It helped me a lot!